# Launch an application with window decorator hints, x/y coordinates, size, etc

Tags: xorg, window-manager, window-decorations, window-geometry

Is there a way to launch an application with a given size, position, and window decorator hints from the command line? I'd like to lock a certain window in a certain place at a size and without a chrome.

Comment: It looks like this question is a duplicate. See also the [answer I provided you there, using Kwin's window specific settings][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94182/48774

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [Devil's Pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/):

> A totally crack-ridden program for freaks and weirdos who want precise
>   control over what windows do when they appear. If you want all XChat
>   windows to be on desktop 3, in the lower-left, at 40% transparency,
>   you can do it.

[Here](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie) is a tutorial, covering the basics.
Since Devil's Pie is no longer maintained, someone made a sequel: [Devilspie2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/).
I've never used the latter as the former still runs OK on my system and does exactly what I want.

Comment: Ah Devil's Pie, great app. I always forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

I use `wmctrl` to control window position and size. It allows you to set things for windows in any Extended Window Manager Hints (EWMH) compatible desktop. Most modern WMs are compatible.

Comment: Pretty genius tool, but is there a way for me to use it to remove the window chrome?

Comment: I don't know the term 'window chrome', it certainly does not show up in the man page for wmctrl nor on the EWMH [webpage](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.5.html) maybe you can find a more common term for it there?

Comment: The window border, the frame, the window controls, etc.

Comment: Those are added by the window manager. If you e.g. run an application on a virtual `xvnc` screen you will have none of that. On the other hand applications in full screen mode are able to do away with them as well on my gnome WM. So there seems to be a way. Sorry, I don't know where to go looking for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the window decoration, but to position applications you can use the the `-geometry` command line argument if the application supports it, though not all applications do. Here an example:

```
xterm -geometry 100x50-0+0  # width x height <location>
```

The locations are

```
+0+0    -  upper left corner
-0+0    -  upper right corner
-0-0    -  lower right corner
+0-0    -  lower left corner
-50+20  -  upper right corner, 20 pixels top distance, 50 pixels right distance
```

An alternative is to use your window manager for that. You can address individual applications for instance by their WM_CLASS. This might as well allow to set size hints or decoration.