# Launching applications from a terminal with specific window size and location

Tags: kde, chrome, window-management, window-geometry

I am running Linux Mint 13, with a KDE 4 desktop manager. I would like to launch applications from a terminal (`konsole` in my specific case) and setting the exact size of the window and the location of the window. As an example, if I launch `Kate` and `Chromium` from a terminal, I want Kate's window the cover the left-half of my screen and I want Chromium to cover the upper-right quarter of my screen.

How can I accomplish this?

ps: I have a 15.6" screen set to a 1920x1080 resolution.

Comment: For some applications: you may use `-geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+X+Y`

Comment: [This link](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/X.7.html#toc6) explains the comment above but only some applications accept `-geometry`. Also, some apps don't use pixels but columns and rows.

Comment: If `-geometry` isn't giving you the result you want, try [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/). `chromium && wmctrl -r chomium -e 'g,x,y,w,h'` You might need a sleep delay before wmctrl. Its a bit more complicated to figure out which chromium window to control when you have multiple open.

Comment: With `-geometry` you can also leave off width and height.  You can also use negative numbers to offset from the right-hand and bottom edges of the screen.

Comment: Maybe I am using it wrong but `wmctrl` did not work for me. I will play around with it some more in the weekend.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to specify the geometry/position during startup, but permanently, simple use `Kwin`'s rule system:

- Launch the desired application
- Right-click on the title-bar or use Alt+F3
- More Actions
- Special Window Settings
- Tab: Window matching

  - Check, whether the values were detected correctly, otherwise use the `Detect Windows Properties` button to capture the data of the target window
- Tab: "Size & Position"

  - Enable the checkboxes of `Position` and `Size`
  - Select, when to apply the Position/Size (Apply Initially, Force, etc.)
  - Set the value for `Position` and/or `Size`

You can do way more than just this using the window rules, see also: [image: Screenshot of window specific settings in kwin].

Comment: I managed to get this working with some programs, however some others have quite random behaviour. Some times it works some times it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Run `xwinifo` and click on the window of the application you want to start.

Note down the line at the bottom

```
-geometry WxH+X+Y
```

where `W`, `H` are the width and Height, `X`, `Y` are the coordinates of the start of the window.

Then try starting the application with that as a command arguements e.g. for Konsole:

```
konsole -geometry WxH+X+Y
```

It should end up reasonably close to where you want. My `Y` coordinate was about 22 pixels too low - but it gives you something to work with. Perhaps the header of the application (decoration?) is not counted properly?

Anyway do this for *all* windows you want.
Put into a shell script and you can run that to start them all up.
e.g.

```
#! /bin/sh

konsole -geometry WxH+X+Y &
konsole -geometry WxH+X+Y &
konsole -geometry WxH+X+Y &
```

Where the exact values for `W`/`H`/`X`/`Y` are obtained from the `wininfo` command.